# XAML не видит ViewModel, хоть пространство имён подключено

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема вот в чем: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где ошибка: 
[image: Ошибка]

Подключённые пространства имён:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама структура проекта: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во viewModel-ах находятся пустые классы (с пространством имен namespace WPFNavigation.ViewModel)
Вопрос: Что не так?

Comment: Пересоберите проект, если не помогло, то давайте полное содержимое файла `FirstVM.cs`.

Comment: Пересобрал проект - помогло. Спасибо